# Oracle Materialized View does not refresh fast on commit

Tags: sql, oracle, materialized-views

I am able to create the MVIEW with REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT. However when i either insert or update the underlying table (e.g Capture_date column) the view did not be refreshed. It only able to refresh when i specify REFRESH FORCE ON COMMIT, but this is something I do not want to do a complete refresh due to performance issue.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON EXP_DC_HST 
WITH SEQUENCE, ROWID 
(ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION, ACTIVITY_TYPE, CD1, CD2, CD3, CD4, Capture_date) 
INCLUDING NEW VALUES; 

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW EXP_DC_AMEND_MVIEW 
PARALLEL 
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT AS 
select H.ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION, H.ACTIVITY_TYPE, H.CD1, H.CD2, H.CD3, H.CD4, H.CD1|| H.CD2|| trim(H.CD3)||'-'||LPAD(H.CD4,2,0) as EXP_DC_NUMBER, 
max(H.Capture_date) as DC_STATUS_TIME 
from EXP_DC_HST H where H.ACTIVITY_TYPE = 'AMENDMENT' 
AND INSTR(H.ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION, 'INFORMAL') = 0 
group by H.ACTIVITY_DESCRIPTION, H.ACTIVITY_TYPE, H.CD1, H.CD2, H.CD3, H.CD4;
```

Comment: Run `DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW('EXP_DC_AMEND_MVIEW');` to get the reason why FAST refresh is not possible. See [EXPLAIN_MVIEW Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_mview.htm#ARPLS67191)

Comment: Check also [Restrictions on Fast Refresh on Materialized Views with Aggregates](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#GUID-932B8CD4-BF60-419A-9202-8A9FD5D24024)

Comment: I think i fullfill the restriction. the MVIEW LOG include all the select column

Comment: At least `COUNT(*)` is missing in your select list.

Comment: no i have tried also.